# How to get the styled, checked option to email?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I've just styled checkboxes on my contact form on my website: cleaners.se/home
My question is: if I choose "telefon" how can I get this option be sent to my email?

On contact form 7 before I just had to type a shortcode, is there anyway I can do it now too?

Here is the code:

```css
.knapp + label {
}

label {
 display: inline;
}

.knapp {
 display: none;
}

.knapp + label {
 background-color: #2CACA9;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 top: 3px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.knapp + label:active, .knapp:checked + label:active {
}

.knapp:checked + label {
 background-color: #2CACA9;
 border: 0;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

.knapp:checked + label:after {
 content: '\2716';
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: "montserrat";
 position: absolute;
 top: 3px;
 left: 15px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    Telefon:<input type="checkbox" id="telefon" class="knapp"><label for="telefon"></label>
        E-post:<input type="checkbox" id="epost" class="knapp"><label for="epost"></label>
    <script>
        $('div .knapp').click(function() {
            checkedState = $(this).attr('checked');
            $(this).parent('div').children('.knapp:checked').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
            });
            $(this).attr('checked', checkedState);
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to do that in contact-form 7 backend

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a normal form, without javascript you can (and with it too)

```
  Telefon: <input type="checkbox" id="telefon" name="telefon" value="true" class="knapp">
```

You receive in the server the checkbox named `telefon` and with value `true`

Comment: Could you please explain it? Show me this in Tidy please.
Will this be an exclusive choice, because it is what I want. It should be just able to choose one option.

Comment: To choose one option the best is a radio button, not a checkbox. Checkbox are for multiple values. Radio button is for a single value. I can remove this answer and make another one.

Comment: First of all tell me if you need to send a mail, have you got a webserver running? PHP? Java? ASP? .NET?